# OCR image with different tables (numbers)

Tags: c#, .net, image-processing, ocr, tesseract

I need to OCR data from the image below:

- Currency Pair and type from the header of the table (i.e.: EUR/USD ATM)
- Values of column 2 (i.e.: 1M, 2M, 3M) and column 5, 6 (i.e: 9.65) (only if text is black, not gray).

In the past for this kind of problem I was using tessnet .NET wrapper for tesseract library. Difference was that tables had a fixed size, hence I had fixed coordinates, and I knew what is the location of each cell so I can OCR value (e.g AUD/JPY 6M = 9.90 / 10.90).

The question I am asking here is, how would you approach problem of detecting X,Y coordinates of each table (as well as width ) ? Problematic here is that below screen is dynamic (not only values), but number of rows in each table is dynamic as well. Hence, if AUD/JPY will have 15 rows then EUR/USD table from 1st column will be in the 2nd column.

How would you approach that problem?

[image: Screen to OCR]

Comment: Looks like this is more of an image processing problem than a tesseract question. I would change the tags accordingly.

Comment: yep this is not OCR related ... you need to find the number of columns , rows and their position from image look into hough transform ,.... but this is not noisy image so may be scan the white areas for black continuous separator will suffice ... do the histogram of white space sizes in H and V directions separate and you should see the cell size in it ... removing the smaller values or too unoccurent

Comment: Thanks guys, I will research Spektre's suggestions.
After tobtobs answer I've started investigating image processing and I found AForge .NET library very helpfull. It allows to detect corners, or find template image in image (which may solve my problem as each table contains same templated images <i.e.: minimize button>).